# Unable to re-install an instance using the original instance name

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

We are trying to uninstall and re-install a 2008R2 instance.  We have uninstalled the database engine but when we tried to re-install it we got the error "Original instance id\name in use".

The instance is on a VM machine (no cluster).  Unfortunately there is another (production) instance on the same machine.

The steps taken were as follows:

1. Back up the databases
2. Uninstall the instance
3. Reboot
4. Attempt re-install failed
5. Review registry for any possible references to the database engine and that instance name and remove them.
6. Attempt re-install - same error.

We did discover that there is a reporting server instance with the old instance name already installed but I wouldn't have thought that the instance name on a reporting server instance would affect the install of a database engine instance.

Any suggestions on what we are missing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reporting server instance *is* going to be enough to block you. Probably any reference to that instance name will be enough. How much time will you lose by *completely* uninstalling SQL Server, along with reporting services? How much time would you lose if you instead chose a different instance name, and updating application connection strings / aliases / etc.?

Comment: Have you reviewed the SQL Server setup log?  Perhaps it contains some hints.

Comment: Turns out the uninstall of reporting services was enough.  If you want to go ahead and put that as an answer @AaronBertrand I'll mark it as correct.  Do you have any idea why though?  I'm fairly sure you can add reporting services to a database engine install later so I would think it would work the other way around too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution IMHO will be to remove reporting services, too, as part of cleaning the old instance off the machine. Until you've cleaned off everything service-related, that instance name still "exists" - and it can be a really thorny and frustrating experience trying to [remove all the registry entries, GUID by agonizing GUID](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition).

I suspect that SQL Server must keep some things around e.g. for connectivity to SSRS from external sources via the instance name. This is why you can't just pave a new instance over top of it.

The other alternative would be to leave your SSRS instance intact, but install the new instance with a different name, and just update application connection strings, aliases, DNS etc. so that they will connect to the new instance name (hopefully this change will be as transparent as possible).